# Ruby on Rails Reset Recaptcha after form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am using the reCAPTCHA gem (https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) on my form in Ruby on Rails.  I am encountering a problem when the user submits a form that has an error (like they forget a field).  When the form is rendered again with the errors, it seems like no matter what, the recaptcha always submits false, even though it shows a checkmark.  If I reload the page, then it works fine.  Is there a way to fix this problem?

Update: I am using the recaptcha on a user signup page, and have essentially followed the code from the gem github page.

Form View:

```
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/error_messages', :locals => { :object => @user} %>
    
    <%= f.label :firstname, "First Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <%= f.label :lastname, "Last Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: 'form-control' %>
      
    <%= f.label :email, "E-mail Address" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <%= f.label :password, "Password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <center><%= recaptcha_tags %></center>
    <br>

    <%= f.submit "Create New User", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    
<% end %>
```

And in the controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if verify_recaptcha(model: @user) && @user.save
    @user.send_activation_email
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

I can see in the parameters when the form is submitted the first time that the g-recaptcha-response exists.  But each subsequent time after a form validation error occurs, the g-recaptcha-response is empty and I get the "reCAPTCHA verification failed, please try again".  This also ignores other form validation errors and only displays the recaptcha error if I submit the form again with form errors.

I have tried using both the enterprise version and the classic version, and have ensured that the keys are correct.  I am using the V2 version that requires a checkmark for "i'm not a robot"

Comment: Share some more information like code snippets and the things you tried.

Comment: Hi Akeel, Updated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue might be related to Turbo, which tries to replace a full page reload by just replacing several pieces of the web page. While this usually works fine, it obviously does not in this case.

I assume that the captcha-challenge is used twice so Google denies the captcha in the second (or third...) try.

Try to disable Turbo for your login form by replacing

```
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true, data: {turbo: "false"} ) do |f| %>
```

For a closer look at Turbo, visit [this](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive)

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick!  I initially got so frustrated that I created a "I am Human" math question, but just went back through and tried it with this code and it seems to work!

Comment: Welcome. You can have a look at https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha for another approach if you don't want to use google

Comment: That's an interesting method, I might try that if I keep having problems with google.  For some reason I continue to get a failed recaptcha the first time its done, even though I get the checkmark (I'm not seeing a recaptcha-response in the parameters), but then works the second time.  I've tried it multiple different times, and it seems to do the same thing each time.  I couldn't find any similar issue reported, any idea what might be causing this?